# How to find Pycharm's Version Using Python

Tags: python, pycharm, version

> I have a program that gets version from (selenium, python and chrome) from my system and compares it with the latest version online.
>
> This is the code to get pythons version from my system

```
    pythonVersion = platform.python_version()
    finalVersion = "Python " + pythonVersion
```

> Now my main problem is trying to get Pycharms version using code. It would be helpful if anyone has any idea on how to do it

Comment: How is Selenium related to this question? Am I missing something?

Comment: My bad, included selenium because the project revolves around using selenium to get latest version of the technology stack from the web!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have researched into it but I was unable to find a solution/plugin that will get the version of the IDE in few lines. This is expected since python has no way of knowing what IDE is being used.

For example,
`Pycharm.getVersion() # This is not possible.`

One of the ways how you can get the version of Pycharm is to look directly in the installation file.

In mine, I have installed PyCharm in the following Dir:

> C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3

And within that there should be a file called `product-info.json`. Looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "PyCharm",
  "version": "2019.3.3",
  "buildNumber": "193.6494.30",
  "productCode": "PY",
  "svgIconPath": "bin/pycharm.svg",
  "launch": [
    {
      "os": "Windows",
      "launcherPath": "bin/pycharm64.exe",
      "javaExecutablePath": "jbr/bin/java.exe",
      "vmOptionsFilePath": "bin/pycharm64.exe.vmoptions"
    }
  ]
}
```

So what you can do is, define an absolute/relative path to this JSON file and within your code and simply access the version by doing `data['version']`, where data holds the JSON objects.

Do the following:

```
import json

with open('/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/Resources/product-info.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    version = data['version']
```

Comment: That is great, thanks so much for taking your time into this! I really appreciate it. Cheers!!

Comment: Why isn't this just an option in pycharm itself X_X.